# kubuntu 14.04 to full screen via virtual box

Tags: ubuntu

I installed kubuntu 14.04 via VirtualBox. 
I tried to change the resolution via the settings, but I have only one option there: 640X480.
I understood that I need to install guest additions, but when I try to do so from 
"Devices"->"insert guest additions CD image", I get this message:
"unable to insert the virtual optical disk c..."

how can I change the resolution to full screen?

Comment: Perhaps this would get more attention over on Ask Ubuntu SE?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this solution, is worked with me:

```
sudo mount -o loop /tmp/VBoxGuestAdditions_5.0.20.iso /mnt
```

and

```
sudo sh /mnt/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11
```

Comment: tried it now, still doesn't work. that's the message I got: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox-guest-x11 : Depends: xorg-video-abi-15
                        Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.14.99.902)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: The one that worked for me was `sudo apt install virtualbox-guest-utils`

Answer (score 0):

There are many answers out in the web about how to do this, I myself have in different platforms have success with many different combinations so this is not by all means a sure answer but it worked for me recently so maybe it will help somebody else. 
Make sure you have build-essentials and module assistant

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential module-assistant
sudo m-a prepare
```

After this is done in your virtualbox window Devices->Insert Guest Additions CD Image. Run, install and reset. (For me that meant restart from the Ubuntu OS, it froze so I restarted the VM completely) 
Godd Luck!

This is the link that already covers this :

http://virtualboxes.org/doc/installing-guest-additions-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

```
Section "Device"
Identifier "Configured Video Device"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier "Monitor0"
VendorName "KDS"
ModelName "VS-7e"
HorizSync 30-70
VertRefresh 50-120
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier "Screen0"
Device "Configured Video Device"
Monitor "Monitor0"
DefaultDepth 24
SubSection "Display"
Viewport 0 0
Depth 24
Modes "1024x768"
EndSubSection
EndSection
```

write the code above and save "xorg.conf" in virtualbox.

Answer (score 0):

This will be the answer of all your  Display resolution scaled  related problem with Virtualbox.
Here i  list all the possible steps  you can follow that will  help to resolve those resolution scaled problem(like zoom out display) and  to switch full screen mode,scaled mode and adjusting window size.

1.At top of Virtualbox:

Go to File -> Preference -> Display and set the Maximum Guest Screen Size to Hint; Width:1920 ; Height:1200

2.Have some knowledge about the Host Key.In my case, Right Ctrl is my Host key.To know yours Virtualbox host Key:

Go to File -> Preference -> Input -> Virtual Machine. Here you can see your Host key combination.

3.(Optional)If you're using some debain distro in Virtualbox; type this command in the terminal of OS that you have installed in Virtualbox:

$sudo apt install build-essential dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r)

4.At top of Virtualbox:

Go to File -> Preference -> View ... Here, you will know about different display mode.

Im my case-

FullScreen Mode-- Host + f

Scaled Mode-- Host + c

Adjust window size-- Host + a

Note-- In my case , Host is my Right ctrl keyword(Host key is  defined as Right ctrl )

Now, you can type those keyword and switch between different display mode...
Like if you type Right ctrl + c , Virtual Machine window will now switch to Scaled Mode

Note:Main Menu bar is Hidden in Scaled Mode.You can access it by pressing Right ctrl + Home